# Fetch data from Api in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks, postman

I  want to fetch the data from this api (refer the screenshots) in reactjs using fetch function..I tried different ways but none of them is working

I am doing this way

```
useEffect(() => {
    // POST request using fetch inside useEffect React hook
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ "firebase_id":"fonnnnjnvQXzyOcXK5kW88PM8jnjnhnhb1"})
    };
    fetch('demo.revon.com/audi/zero/li', requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data =>  console.log(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to call your API without https://localhost:3000 in front of your API link.

You forgot to put HTTP or HTTPS so it consider a subfolder of localhost:3000.

You must do something like that : (or http if not https)

```
fetch('https://demo.revon.com/audi/zero/li', requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data =>  console.log(data));
```

Regards

Comment: .Also I think I am doing wrong with requestOptions thing

Comment: Do you  think I should add the authentication bearer token?

Comment: If the API requires an authentication with a token that's inside header (bearer etc..) yes you have to !

Comment: How to add that? how should I write the requestOptions  part?

Comment: `fetch('https://demo.revon.com/audi/zero/li, { 
    method: 'POST', 
    headers: new Headers({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + yourToken, 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }), 
    body: JSON.stringify({ "firebase_id":"fonnnnjnvQXzyOcXK5kW88PM8jnjnhnhb1"})
});`

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need to mention https:// in the fetch url

Comment: I think I am doing wrong with requestOptions thing

Comment: You’ll need to append that https:// infront of your backend url, along with that i see you are configuring authorisation in postman but you aren’t setting the Authorization header in the post request

Comment: yess..how should i do that

Comment: How should I write the whole requestOptions ?

Answer (score 1):

`requestOptions` is not the issue here!

---

You are OBVIOUSLY hitting the `localhost` domain, not `demo.revon`.
Insert the full URL: `https://demo.revon.com/audi/zero/li`